# C++ stl collections or linked lists

Tags: c++, data-structures, collections, linked-list

I'm developing a OpenGL based simulation in C++. I'm optmizing my code now and i see throughout the code the frequently use of std:list and std:vector. What is the more performatic: to continue using C++ stl data structs or a pointer based linked list? The main operation that involve std::list and std::vector is open a iterator and loop through all items in the data structs and apply some processing

Comment: If you haven't profiled your code yet, you're asking the question prematurely. You should know before you get here whether the std::list or std::vector are taking a disproportionate amount of time.

Comment: I suspect if you profile your code you will see that your use of STL is not the slowest thing.  Don't bother asking this question until it is the slowest thing... in fully optimized release mode.

Comment: Just FYI, "performant" is the word that I hear most often for what you call "performatic".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about stl containers of pointers?

It is highly unlikely that you will be able to develop better performing structures than the builtin. The only down part is the containers actually do contain copies of objects stored in them. If you're worried about this memory overhead (multiple structs hodling multiple copies of same objects, breaking consistency across the table) you should think about using stl structures of pointers to what you need.

Algorithmically speaking, the structure you need is implemented in the stl so you should use it. There is no need to reimplement the same structure.

Answer (score 4):

Use C++ STL data structs, but use them efficiently. If you're using std::list and std::vector, look up such functions as find, for_each, accumulate, etc.
Here's some good reading:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/

Read the sections on algorithm, numeric, and functional. Also, I strongly recommend Scott Meyers' Effective STL.